# ValueError in user code because of custom definition train_step function

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am trying to build my custom graph neural network, however I do not fully understand the Keras API. Is there anyone who has experience in how to build custom neural networks in the Keras API? I have looked at [this documentation](https://keras.io/guides/customizing_what_happens_in_fit/). But my application doesn't seem to work due to a `ValueError in user code`.

The problem lies in the *input training data* and the *input of the first layer*. In the MNIST data set, the data points is a vector composed of pixel values. And you plug these vectors in the first layer as input layer.

However, in my case my data points are *matrices*. The input of the first layer is a row from this matrix. Per row the loss is calculated and added to the previously calculated loss. Eventually obtaining a cumulative loss per row. Then we backpropagate using the cumulative loss of the entire matrix. Then the next matrix in the dataset is called, etc....

I tried to define a custom `train_step` function, but failed miserably at it:

```
def compile(self, learning_rate=0.0001):
    optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)
    self.model.compile(optimizer=optimizer)
    
  def train(self, x_train, batch_size, num_epochs):
    self.model.fit(x_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=num_epochs)
    
  def train_step(self, data):
        DFS_sequence = data
        loss = 0
        bce = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(logits=False)
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            for i in range(len(DFS_sequence)): 
                s_i = DFS_sequence[i][j] #onehotencoding
                s_i_star = self(s_i, training=True)  # Forward pass
                # Compute our own loss
                loss += bce(s_i, s_i_star)
                mae_metric.update_state(s_i, s_i_star)

        # Compute gradients
        trainable_vars = self.trainable_variables
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars)

        # Update weights
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))

        # Compute our own metrics
        loss_tracker.update_state(loss)
        return {"loss": loss_tracker.result(), "mae": mae_metric.result()}

  @property
  def metrics(self):
        return [loss_tracker, mae_metric]
```

The error Im getting:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-1369147041330042> in <module>
    183 if __name__== "__main__":
    184   x_train = dummy_data
--> 185   gnn = train(x_train, LEARNING_RATE, BATCH_SIZE, EPOCHS)

<command-1369147041330042> in train(x_train, learning_rate, batch_size, epochs)
    177   gnn.summary()
    178   gnn.compile(learning_rate)
--> 179   gnn.train(x_train, batch_size, epochs)
    180   return gnn
    181 

<command-1369147041330042> in train(self, x_train, batch_size, num_epochs)
     46 #                   epochs=num_epochs,
     47 #                   shuffle=False)
---> 48     self.model.fit(x_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=num_epochs)
     49 
     50   def train_step(self, data):
```

Code to reproduce:

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
import random
import copy
import numpy as np

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dropout, LSTM, Dense
import numpy
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.losses import BinaryCrossentropy

class GNN:
  """
  GNN is a graph neural network.
  """
  
  def __init__(self, input_shape_x_train):
    
    
    self.input_shape_x_train = input_shape_x_train
    self.input_shape_emb = input_shape_x_train[1:] # (6, 14)
    self.amount_edges = input_shape_x_train[0] #12
    self.input_shape_mlps = 256
    self.embedding_shape = 92
    self.mlps_shape = 512    
    self._num_lstm_cells = 4    
    
    self.model = None
    
    self._build()
    
  def summary(self):
    self.model.summary()
    
  def compile(self, learning_rate=0.0001):
    optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)
    self.model.compile(optimizer=optimizer)
    
  def train(self, x_train, batch_size, num_epochs):
#     self.model.fit(x_train,
#                   x_train,
#                   batch_size=batch_size,
#                   epochs=num_epochs,
#                   shuffle=False)
    self.model.fit(x_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=num_epochs)
    
  def train_step(self, data):
        x = data #Dit is met één trainingdatapoint wat een DFS sequence is
        DFS_sequence = x
        loss = 0
        bce = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(logits=False)
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            for i in range(len(DFS_sequence)): 
                s_i = DFS_sequence[i][j] #onehotencoding
                s_i_star = self(s_i, training=True)  # Forward pass
                # Compute our own loss
                loss += bce(s_i, s_i_star)
                mae_metric.update_state(s_i, s_i_star)

        # Compute gradients
        trainable_vars = self.trainable_variables
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars)

        # Update weights
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))

        # Compute our own metrics
        loss_tracker.update_state(loss)
        return {"loss": loss_tracker.result(), "mae": mae_metric.result()}

  @property
  def metrics(self):
        # We list our `Metric` objects here so that `reset_states()` can be
        # called automatically at the start of each epoch
        # or at the start of `evaluate()`.
        # If you don't implement this property, you have to call
        # `reset_states()` yourself at the time of your choosing.
        return [loss_tracker, mae_metric]


  def _build(self):
    self._build_model()
    
  def _build_model(self):
    num_neurons = self.embedding_shape
    embedding_input = Input(shape=self.input_shape_emb, name="embedding_input")
    lstm_input_1 = Dense(num_neurons, name="embedding_dense")(embedding_input)
    lstm_input_2 = LSTM(256, activation='relu', dropout=0.1, return_sequences=True, name = f"lstm_cell_1")(lstm_input_1)
    lstm_input_3 = LSTM(256, activation='relu', dropout=0.1, return_sequences=True, name = f"lstm_cell_2")(lstm_input_2)
    lstm_input_4 = LSTM(256, activation='relu', dropout=0.1, return_sequences=True, name = f"lstm_cell_3")(lstm_input_3)
    mlps_input = LSTM(256, activation='relu', dropout=0.1, return_sequences=False, name = f"lstm_cell_4")(lstm_input_4)
    
    mlps_output = self._add_mpls(mlps_input)
    multinomials_output = tf.convert_to_tensor([self._add_multinomials(mlps_output)])
    
    self.model = tf.keras.Model(embedding_input, multinomials_output, name="gnn")    
  
  def _add_mpls(self, mlps_input):
    x = mlps_input
    num_hidden_layers = self.mlps_shape
    MLP_hidden_1 = Dense(num_hidden_layers, name = "MLP_hidden_1")(x)
    MLP_hidden_2 = Dense(num_hidden_layers, name = "MLP_hidden_2")(x)
    
    MLP_output_1 = Dense(7, activation = 'softmax', name = "MLP_output_1")(MLP_hidden_1)
    MLP_output_2 = Dense(7, activation = 'softmax', name = "MLP_output_2")(MLP_hidden_2)
    
    MLP_vertically_stacked = {
    "MLP_output_1": MLP_output_1,
    "MLP_output_2": MLP_output_2,
      
    }
    
    return MLP_vertically_stacked
    
  def _add_multinomials(self, mlps_output):
    generated_output_1 = tf.random.categorical(tf.math.log([mlps_output["MLP_output_1"][0]]), 1) 
    generated_output_1 = tf.squeeze(tf.one_hot(generated_output_1, depth=7), axis=1)[0] 
    generated_output_2 = tf.random.categorical(tf.math.log([mlps_output["MLP_output_2"][0]]), 1) 
    generated_output_2 = tf.squeeze(tf.one_hot(generated_output_2, depth=7), axis=1)[0] 
    Multinomial_output_in_onehot_encoding = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=0)([generated_output_1, generated_output_2])
    
    return Multinomial_output_in_onehot_encoding
    
    
################################################ train.py below ############################    
#First making a dummy dataset


LEARNING_RATE = 0.00005
BATCH_SIZE = 32
EPOCHS = 20

dummy_data = []
dummy_DFS_code1 = [[0,1],[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5],[5,0]]
dummy_data = [dummy_DFS_code1]*12 #+  [dummy_DFS_code2]*12
random.shuffle(dummy_data)
#make lists of all labels

element_0 = [element[0] for element in DFS_code for DFS_code in dummy_data]
element_1 = [element[1] for element in DFS_code for DFS_code in dummy_data]

element_0 = to_categorical(element_0,num_classes=num_classes_timestamp1)
element_1 = to_categorical(element_1,num_classes=num_classes_timestamp1)

l = 0
for DFS_code in dummy_data:
    for j in range(len(DFS_code)):
        DFS_code[j][0] = element_0[l]
        DFS_code[j][1] = element_1[l]
        #print(l)
        l += 1
def flatten(t):
    return [item for sublist in t for item in sublist]

for i in range(len(dummy_data)):
    for j in range(len(dummy_data[i])):
        dummy_data[i][j] = np.hstack(dummy_data[i][j])
        dummy_data[i][j] = np.asarray(dummy_data[i][j])
    dummy_data[i] = np.asarray(dummy_data[i])
dummy_data = np.asarray(dummy_data)

dummy_data = tf.convert_to_tensor(dummy_data)
dummy_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dummy_data)


#########################################################



def train(x_train, learning_rate, batch_size, epochs):
  gnn = GNN(
    input_shape_x_train = (12, 6, 14)
  )
  gnn.summary()
  gnn.compile(learning_rate)
  gnn.train(x_train, batch_size, epochs)
  return gnn


if __name__== "__main__":
  x_train = dummy_data
  gnn = train(x_train, LEARNING_RATE, BATCH_SIZE, EPOCHS)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, which does *not* work by simply throwing all our code here as-is; please see how to create a [mre] (emphasis on *minimal*), as well as why [a wall of code isn't helpful](https://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/)

Comment: Hi, I understand. I shrunk the dummy_data.

Comment: And I have added a highlight of the part of my code that is causing this trouble.